# Managed local storage for blobs

Tags: .net, storage, blob

The general consensus these days seems to be that you do not store binary large objects in your relational database, as its not really optimised for that sort of thing, and instead put it into a dedicated storage engine.

Can anyone suggest a solution for the .Net platform, along the lines of the Microsoft Azure Blob Storage engine, but kept local to the organisation?

Comment: @Moo: Sharepoint stores data in blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql Server 2008 there is functionality to administrate blob information in the database.  It really stores it on the file system, so you get the best of both worlds.